# Measure runtime of function with arguments using timeit.timeit

Tags: python, runtime, timeit

I would like to create a function. The code doesn't work, but you can get the idea what I want to get:

```
def time_test(func, test_data: int) -> float:
    # should return a runtime of given function
    return timeit(stmt=func(test_data), number=10000)
```

Obviously, I do have to pass as `stmt` something callable or a string with executable code. That's why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to do this in a correct way.

Example how I want to use `time_test()` function:

```
from timeit import timeit
# To be tested
def f1(argument_ops):
    result = 0
    for i in range(argument_ops):
        result += 4
    return result

def f2(argument_ops):
    result = 0
    for i in range(argument_ops):
        for j in range(argument_ops):
            result += 4
    return result

# test function to be implemented
def time_test(func, test_data: int) -> float:
    runtime = 0
    # implement this, it should return a runtime of a given function. Function needs
    # argument test_data.
    return runtime

# example of usage
print(time_test(f1, 96))
print(time_test(f2, 24))
```

Comment: Use `setup` to pass a string which sets-up the test data, e.g `'x = 3000'` and maybe it can also import the necessary function, so `'x = 3000; from __main__ import f1 as func'` then the statement can just be `func(x)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you can use the `globals` argument, which takes a namespace in which to execute the statement, to do this relatively easily. Something to the effect of:

```
def time_test(func, test_data: int) -> float:
    gs = dict(func=func, test_data=test_data)
    runtime = timeit("func(test_data)", globals=gs)
    # implement this, it should return a runtime of a given function. Function needs argument test_data.
    return runtime
```

Note, by default this times how long it takes to the statement `1000000` times.

Comment: Wow! That's perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: @panSteven4 I edited it slightly to a simpler approach, reconsidering the use of `globals().copy()` as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it this way which involves passing the function definition to the `time_test()` function as well as the function name and arguments:

```
from timeit import timeit

# To be tested
f1_def = """
def f1(argument_ops):
    result = 0
    for i in range(argument_ops):
        result += 4
    return result
"""

f2_def = """
def f2(argument_ops):
    result = 0
    for i in range(argument_ops):
        for j in range(argument_ops):
            result += 4
    return result
"""

# test function
def time_test(func, test_data: int, setup: str) -> float:
    stmt = f'{func}({test_data!r})'
    runtime = timeit(stmt, setup)
    return runtime

# example of usage
print(time_test('f1', 96, setup=f1_def))  # -> 4.069019813000001
print(time_test('f2', 24, setup=f2_def))  # -> 34.072881441999996
```

Comment: Yes, this works "locally" but the issue with this is, that I want to test hundreds of functions. I would have to write a setup for every single function. I want this to be automatic. Is there any way to get a definition of a function to a string automatically?

However, juanpa.arrivillaga found other way of doing this, so there is no need to figure this out. Thank you anyways.